# Print a line from a 2-dimensional mixed array (containing integers and floating data types) in Python2

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

How do I print a line from a 2-dimensional mixed array (containing integers and floating data types) without the square brackets and the spacing in the floating types and decimal point in integers?
I want to use:

```
    for line in xd:
    print line,
```

to get the final output
The code i tried is as follows:

```
    import numpy
    x =[[1.456, 2, 3],
         [4, 5.231, 6],
         [7, 8, 9.145]]
    x=numpy.array(x)
    xd=numpy.array2string(x, separator='\t')
    for line in xd:
       print line,
```

This is the output from the code

```
[ [   1 . 4 5 6       2 .             3 .       ]  
  [   4 .             5 . 2 3 1       6 .       ]   
  [   7 .             8 .             9 . 1 4 5 ] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `x` is a list of lists

```
In [14]: x =[[1.456, 2, 3],
    ...:          [4, 5.231, 6],
    ...:          [7, 8, 9.145]]
In [15]: x
Out[15]: [[1.456, 2, 3], [4, 5.231, 6], [7, 8, 9.145]]
In [16]: for row in x:
    ...:     print(row)
    ...:     
[1.456, 2, 3]
[4, 5.231, 6]
[7, 8, 9.145]
```

We could set up a Python formatted print expression for each `row`.

But first look at what happens when you make an array:

```
In [17]: arr=np.array(x)
In [18]: arr
Out[18]: 
array([[ 1.456,  2.   ,  3.   ],
       [ 4.   ,  5.231,  6.   ],
       [ 7.   ,  8.   ,  9.145]])
```

This is a 2d array - of the dtype float, the dtype that can hold both the ints and the floats.  Formally you've lost the distinction between float and ints.

Trying to display this array without decimals and without [] is a lot harder than for the original list.  The array formatting puts a lot of effort into lining up the columns, in other words making a pretty table like display.  If the array is large lines will wrap, and it will start to add ellipsis.  So from a display stand point, you actually loose control when making an array.

`np.savetxt` may help; it can be used to write the rows without []; 
Drawing inspiration from `savetxt` (and how it formats rows)

```
In [21]: for row in x:
    ...:     print('%6s %6s %6s'%tuple(row))
    ...:     
 1.456      2      3
     4  5.231      6
     7      8  9.145

In [22]: for row in arr:
    ...:     print('%6s %6s %6s'%tuple(row))
    ...:     
 1.456    2.0    3.0
   4.0  5.231    6.0
   7.0    8.0  9.145
```

So if you are picky about the format of the numbers, stick with the list of lists, and study up on the Python formatting system (whether the `%` or `.format` version).  For example `%g` works with the array as well as with the list

```
In [29]: for row in arr:
    ...:     print('%6.2g %6.3g %6g'%tuple(row))
    ...:     
   1.5      2      3
     4   5.23      6
     7      8  9.145
```